# What is that thing between CSS "selectors" called?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, css-selectors, naming

What do you call ***these***:

```
body > p + p
```

in a CSS selector? Are they:

- Relational operators
- Position-based criteria
- Something else?

I just have no idea what to call them. Is there an official name?

(And, also, are there official names for `a b c` in `a b c, d e f` and `a` in `a b c`?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#combinators they are called "combinators".

1. (space character) = descendant combinator
2. `>` (angle bracket or greater-than sign) = child combinator
3. `+` (plus mark) = adjacent sibling combinator
4. `~` (tilde) = general sibling combinator

Comment: A little historical trivia: the only combinator in existence in CSS1 was the descendant combinator. Selectors with the descendant combinator were called [contextual selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors); however the combinator itself did not receive a name until CSS2; in CSS1 it was simply referred to as whitespace, significant in the selector grammar.

Answer (score 7):

As identified by Tom Haws, the operators between the simple selectors are called [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax). In CSS2 there were only three: `+`, `>`, and the space combinator.

- The space is the combinator used in a [CSS descendent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).
- `>` is the combinator used in a [CSS child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).
- `+` is the combinator used in a [CSS adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

In each case, the 'selector' is the full combination of the simple selectors and the combinators.

The range of valid combinators expanded, once [CSS Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) was standardized, to include the `~` or "subsequent-sibling" combinator.

Answer (score 3):

The characters or whitespace between tag names are called combinators, see for example [General Sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). These are `>` and `+` in your example.

The tags in your example are called *simple selector* in CSS2 and CSS3. If you would have `a b c` that would be called *sequence of simple selectors* in CSS3 but *simple selector* in CSS2. The term *simple selector* does only refer to one element name in CSS3 such as `a` in `a b c`.

Or as the section [Selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax) states

> A selector is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors separated by combinators.

`a b c, d e f` is called the [*group of selectors*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping) where the group members are the selectors `a b c` and `d e f`. `a b c` is a *selector*, or *sequence of simple selectors*, composed of the *simple selectors* `a`, `b`, `c` combined by the *combinator* whitespace. The last sentence is only valid for CSS3.