# how to make pop-up image using css3?

Tags: html, image, css, popup

Hello i have been trying a lot to do the pop-up image effect using CSS and CSS3 but the result is nothing i don't know what is the problem, i think it's because of the pseudo-classes don't work with me like (visited,actived and focus etc..) just hover works with me so could anybody help me solve this problem?

what i mean by pop-up image effect is : you know when clicking on an image on Facebook that image is popped up with it's real size and the background is become a little bit more dark?

By the way does anyone know what is the problem with the pseudo-classes why they don't work with me?

thanks

```
 <style type="text/css">
           .pop{
             border: 1px solid #000 ;
             border-radius: 15%;
             width: 200px;
             height: 200px;
           }
             .pop:active{
             width:500px ;
             height:500px;
             position:relative;
             right: -65px;
             top: 200px ;
             background-color:#000;
             }
```

```
<img class='pop' src="C:/Users/mohammad ghazi/Desktop/Xhtml folder/friends.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us give you quality answers, you should post your coding, what you have tried, and the desired effects. See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a explanation of a good question. Good Luck!

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23zgvg1f/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a lightbox. Their are many good tutorials on how to make a pure css one, here is a few of them:
http://andornagy.com/pure-css-image-lightbox/
http://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2013/11/01/responsive-css3-lightbox-with-no-javascript/
http://www.thecssninja.com/xhtml/futurebox
The problem with using `:target` as a CSS click event is that it has some downsides such as page jumps or browser history.
You can avoid the downsides of `:target` by using the [checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/):
Make a checkbox and hide it:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
```

Then, make the image you want to have a lightbox for, and wrap it in a `<label>`

```
<label for="check">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" width="200">
</label>
```

Now, write the HTML for the lightbox:

```
<label for="check">
<div id="cover">
<div id="box">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" width="400">
</div>
</div>
</label>
```

And now, for the CSS magic!
Create the lightbox css:

```
#cover{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
display:none;
}
#box{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
width:400px;
height:400px;
border:10px solid white;
}
```

This creates and centers the lightbox.
Now you need to add the click event:

```
#check:checked ~ label #cover{
display:block;
}
```

This CSS means, If `#check` is checked (`:checked` selector), find the sibling (~) with a id of #cover inside a label element and apply the rule to it.
That's it!
Your coding should look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
<label for="check">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" width="200">
    </label>
<label for="check">
    <div id="cover">
    <div id="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" width="400">
    </div>
    </div>
    </label>
```

And CSS:

```
  #check:checked ~ label #cover{
    display:block;
    }
#cover{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
    }
    #box{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:10px solid white;
    }
```

## [SEE THIS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/fkvftff2/5/)

Comment: thanks a lot it's a great way but there is one little code that i don't understand it 

    #check:checked ~ label #cover{
display:block;
}

this is it and i don't understand what is the ~ for 

also i want to what does the [for] in the label tag do

thanks

Comment: Added explanation about the CSS. The for in the labels tells the browser that that is a label for the checkbox with the id check. Glad i could help!

Comment: Also, if this is the answer you are using, you should mark it as accepted so people coming later are more likely to notice it.

Comment: thanks again i understand the for but actually still don't understand this ~ and what it's name by the way does it have a specific name that i could search for

Comment: i have marked it i don't know how it's gone am sorry for that here i marked it again don't worry

Comment: That's fine. it is called a combinator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370493/what-is-that-thing-between-css-selectors-called

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but most easy way to do this is you can use lighbox tools like: FancyBox, Colorbox plugins etc.

### Fancy Box: http://fancybox.net

### Color Box: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Alternatively you can use: jQuery Lightbox Generator

### jQuery Lightbox Generator: http://visuallightbox.com/

For the problem with pseudo-classes, what i got from your question is you want to enlarge image?
Check this Jsfiddle:

```
  ` http://jsfiddle.net/23zgvg1f/1/ `
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for helping but actually am looking for learning some codes so i don't like to use plugins

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're going for is definitely javascript or Jquery. here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0oa9stt/) which shows what i'm on about.

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://0.s3.envato.com/files/19320511/Scenery%2080x80%20Avatar.png"/></a>

<div id="divLargerImage"></div>
<div id="divOverlay"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('a img').click(function () {
    var $img = $(this);
    $('#divLargerImage').html($img.clone().height(250).width(250)).add($('#divOverlay')).fadeIn();
});

$('#divLargerImage').add($('#divOverlay')).click(function () {
    $('#divLargerImage').add($('#divOverlay')).fadeOut(function () {
        $('#divLargerImage').empty();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
    #divLargerImage
    {
        display: none;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        left: 35%;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    #divOverlay
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #CCC;
        opacity: 0.5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 98;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your helping a lot but actually am not that good in JQuery that's why i don't use it but thanks you have answered my question (Y)

Comment: i dont either, but it makes things a lot easier when you know about them.

Comment: yeah i know that and i will learn them after i become a professional in Css3 and java script :D